# Spring Boot 2 - Error Handling with POJO Responses

Tags: spring-boot

Trying to configure a Spring Boot 2.x.x web app to handle errors by returning custom POJO responses based on thrown Exceptions. For this, I have created an example `ErrorHandler` class as follows:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

import org.abc.api.model.view.MissingFieldError;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MissingFieldException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ResponseEntity<MissingFieldError> handleMissingFieldException(MissingFieldException ex, WebRequest req) {
        MissingFieldError error = new MissingFieldError();
        error.setCode("MISSING_FIELD");
        error.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        error.setField(ex.getField());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

In testing, when a `MissingFieldException` is thrown in the `Controller` class, the `ErrorHandler` fails to respond with a `MissingFieldError` as expected. Instead, the app just logs a:

`SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/abc] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.abc.api.error.MissingFieldException: Field value not specified] with root cause
org.abc.api.error.MissingFieldException`.

If I update the `ErrorHandler` to return a `String` instead of `MissingFieldError` then the error is handled okay and a `400 Bad Request` is indeed received by the calling client. But we would like to return a POJO which gets displayed on the client's browser as XML (`@RequestMapping(produces = "application/xml")`).

What am I missing or what do I need to configure in order to be able to return POJOs instead of Strings for error handled responses?

Currently gradle dependencies are as follows:

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.4'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.4'
compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.0.0.M6") {
    exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
}
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.0.M6"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a missing dependency. Adding:

`compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.9.4'`

solved the problem.